# How to fix water bugged screen?

Tags: broken-screen

I have Asus Zenfone Max Pro M1. The screen got splashed with the water and the touch is not responding.

[image: water bugged screen]

How to fix it?

Comment: Shit down the device, dry it in rice for a few weeks and if that doe snot help go to a repair shop.

Comment: @robert, i already did that, and i have new phone and im gonna buy a new screen from Ebay for 20$. Just needed to know before buying stuff. Thanks.

Comment: If that darkness on the right is the actual screen and not a shadow then it was likely beyond saving. "Press F to show respects". [This iFixIt answer](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/374050/Why+is+there+a+spreading+black+spot+on+my+screen#answer374052) goes into pretty good detail about what happens to wet phones and why rice is so often ineffective, along with giving a very oversimplified attempt-to-fix guide.